# How to disable WC_AJAX::update_order_review() in checkout page?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make the checkout process faster, currently, woocommerce is refreshing `review-order` based on choosing a state, and typing a zip code. While I use a flat rate, location is not an essential parameter in price.

- How I can disable `WC_AJAX::update_order_review()` to prevent loading order review table?
- Will disabling `WC_AJAX::update_order_review()` cause a problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, add the following line in `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'sallar_woocommerce_custom_update_checkout', 50);

function sallar_woocommerce_custom_update_checkout()
{
  if (is_checkout()) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(document).ready($ => {

    $('input').on('change', () => {

      $('body').off('update_checkout');

    });

  });

</script>
<?php } }
```